# Indexing books with Elasticsearch: which pages contain hits?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm indexing books with Elasticsearch to search them with FTS. One of the requirements is that I have to display numbers of pages that contain hits.

I initially planned to include page separators in indexed string, then get highlights when I search and count page separators before highlighted words. On a second thought, I'm concerned about performance issues. Some books may be up to 500 KB in size. Counting words in strings that long sounds like a *bad* idea. It would be much better to compare offsets of matched words with offsets of page separators. As I understand, `with_positions_offsets` causes ES to store these offsets, so ideally I'd like it to do the job for me.

**Can this be done in ES? What are alternative solutions to finding on which page of a book a hit is?**

Comment: Why don't you store your books as index and each page as a document in the index with the a page number field ? Elasticsearch can handle millions of docs with relatively low performance issues. This way you can easily get the page number of any match to your query.

Comment: @adityasinghraghav I've deleted my previous comment because I misunderstood you. With the approach you're proposing what would happen if an exact hit spans across two pages? I suppose it would get a score penalty?

Comment: that could possibly be an issue, depending upon your query if you are looking to find an exact match (no tolerance) there will be no hits if it's on different pages, and in case your query is tolerant and accepts a partial match than there will be two separate hits and both will have a lower score than they would have had if they were on the same page.